# How can we pass different parameters from Angular while making Webservice call?

Tags: angular

I have created 2 endpoints 1) http://localhost:4000/show.do 2) http://localhost:4000/posts/payload
Now I have created a common service class commonService which has 2 methods get and post. I am performing USER Crud operation so created a UserService and calling CommonService methods. My code looks like below.

```
 export class CommonService {

  constructor(private url:string, private http: HttpClient) { }

getAll()
{
 return this.http.get(this.url)    
.pipe(map((response:any)=>response));
}

create(resource)
{
  return this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(resource))
  .pipe(map((response:any)=>response.json()));
}
}
```

My UserService code looks like below

```
export class UserService extends CommonService {

  constructor(http:HttpClient) {
    super("http://localhost:4000/show.do", http);
   }  
}
```

So my issue is as I've already defined get url here so easy to make getAll method call from component. However for second url I want to make a call from here itself instead of creating a new service class.

Currently I am calling like below:

```
    export class UserComponent implements ngInit{
    constructor(private service:UserService){}

   ngOnInit()
      {
        this.service.getAll();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would provide a base url and extend it in every method:

```
constructor(http:HttpClient) {
    super("http://localhost:4000", http);
}  

...    
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/show.do`)
...


...
this.http.post(`${this.url}/posts/payload`,JSON.stringify(resource))
...
```

Also some more tipps:

`.pipe(map((response:any)=>response));`

this is redundant you map response to response.

`JSON.stringify(resource)`

You do not have to use JSON.stringify angular can handle that by itself

`.pipe(map((response:any)=>response.json()));`

This is also not needed, if you want you can use generics to add type information

`this.http.get<MyCalss>(...)`

Comment: but if will hard code like return this.http.get(`${this.url}/show.do`) and suppose next we have Admin section where url is like http://localhost:4000/getlist.do then will need to create a new class. I want to keep one generic class where only I pass URLs from different service and it works.

Comment: Do I understand it right, you want to have one service where you can provide different urls and call get post, put etc. and thats it?

Comment: Yes. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `this.http.request` method which consumes a HttpRequest Object

```
call(methodtype,url,object){
    const req = new HttpRequest(methodtype, url, object, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      map(event => {//do your stuff}),
      tap(message => {//here also }),
      last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
      catchError(this.handleError(file))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make `CommonService` takes a root url not the entire url and define a specific suffix for each method. See the exemple below :

```js
export class CommonCrudService {

  constructor(private rootUrl: string, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/get')
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response));
  }

  create(resource) {
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/post', JSON.stringify(resource))
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

Your user service :

```js
export class UserService extends CommonService {

  constructor(http:HttpClient) {
    super("http://localhost:4000/user", http);
   }  
}
```

I suggest yo to see how to define urls in [RESTful](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) APIs, it could help you to write standard/elegant solution.